# LTI-Civil Project wierd error when exported to a JAR

Tags: java, native, webcam

Outline:
1. My project uses LTI-CIVIL to capture webcam.
2. In Eclipse, everything works fine.
3. As LTI_CIVIL uses native libraries to access hardware, I have opted to use JarClassLoader (info found here http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php#download) which allows for the native libraries to be unpacked into a temporary folder at runtime. Everything works great and I can even access the webcam capture stream until...
I try to work with the Image handed in from the webcam which is of type com.lti.civil.NativeVideoFormat. The problem is that when run from the executable jar, it says that this class does not implement com.lti.civl.VideoFormat when it obviously does. I have even printed out the getClass() of the code running on eclipse and verified that the webcam Image is both of the same type. However, when I printout if the getClass() instanceof NativeVideoFormat, in the eclipse version this prints true, but in the jar version it prints false.

Interestingly, this problem has appeared before, but with no solution:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10637883&#10637883

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that "it obviously does" implement that interface, but I think that the problem is that it **actually** doesn't.  I think you have multiple "incarnations" of that interface type.

The real type of a class (or interface) at runtime depends is the identity of the `Class` object:

- If `clazz == clazz2` then they represent the same type.  (The `equals(Object)` method on a `Class` tests the same condition ...)
- Otherwise they don't, *irrespective* of the class names.

It would appear that your application's use of classloaders has resulted in one `.class` file being loaded twice in two different class loaders.  I suspect that your `JarClassLoader` instance doesn't have the correct parent classloader.

Comment: I have looked into the output of the debug logger from the JarClassLoader but really am at a loss of how to proceed.

Could part of the problem be that I am using eclipse's automatic jar export wizard?

Comment: *"Could part of the problem be that I am using eclipse's automatic jar export wizard?"* - It is unlikely.  The problem is most likely in the way that you are using that custom classloader.  Did you do it the way that the website recommends ... by completely replacing your 'main' class?